# How to fire an ended event with a videojs player on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html, video, video.js

I am trying to show an alert on an android device once a video has finished playing in the videojs html5 player. I'm using javascript below the end of my video tag and I can't figure out why it isn't showing the alert.

HTML for video player

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" autoplay preload="auto" width="640" height="360" data-setup="{}">

        <!--poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"-->
          <!--Gets where video is locally stored and plays it-->
            <source ng-src="{{getFilePath()}}" type='video/mp4'>
            <!--<source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type='video/webm'>-->
          <!--If there is no javascript for some reason-->
            <p class="vjs-no-js">
                To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
                <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
            </p>

</video>
```

Javascript here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myPlayer = videojs("my-video");
     videojs("my-video").ready(function () {
        myPlayer.on("ended", function () {
         alert('The video has ended');
     });
});
</script>
```

If anyone could please show me why this isn't working and how to fix it I would gladly appreciate it. Also as a side note if anyone knows how to disable the scrollbar without disabling all of the controls that would be fantastic as well.

Thank you

Comment: videojs("my-video").on("ended",function(){}); should work too

Comment: Yeah I thought that would work but it seems the end event hasn't triggered properly. I'll continue to investigate as it might be something else wrong with the application. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myPlayer =  videojs("my-video",{},function(){
      // the third parameter is the ready event on the constructor
      this.on("ended",function(){alert('The video has ended');});
    });
</script>
```

or this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myPlayer =  videojs("my-video");
    // myPlayer object is defined, so It is ready to listen events
    myPlayer.on("ready",function(){
      alert('The player is ready');
    });
    myPlayer.on("ended",function(){
      alert('The video has ended');
    });
</script>
```

**or try using the html5:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myPlayer =  videojs("my-video");
    // We will use getElementsByTagName, because videojs can wrap
    // your video inside a div, and changes its id. Your id will
    // be the videojs div wrapper.
    // Get the first video element found and append the listener
    var html5_video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    html5_video.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
      alert('The video has ended');
    });
</script>
```

The videojs api exposes these events: ended, error, loadeddata, loadedmetadata, timeupdate, useractive, userinactive and volumechange.

But there are others supported by the standard html5 video tag like play, pause, etc.

Happy code :-)

Comment: I tried both of those solutions and they didn't work unfortunately although I think it might be to do with the way my project is setup because I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work. I'm probably going to move onto videogular anyway as I am working with angularjs. Thank you for your help anyway, I'm sure your solutions will help many others who look at this page. :)

Comment: Try the html5 video listener instead. Check the next answer. I will add it to the post.

Comment: Ok I will try that soon and keep you updated if it works. Thanks once again for the help